# Is it normal to also see my UTM code campaigns under Google Analytics "Site Content"?

Tags: google-analytics

I can see my UTM code campaigns in the "All Campaigns" report:

**Acquisition > Campaigns > All Campaigns report**

However, I'm also seeing them on my "Site Content" reports too, is that normal?

**Behavior > Site Content > All Pages**

Does it duplicate my data, such as pageviews?

*** Added screenshots (blurred out site name)*

Campaigns > All Campaigns report
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCRaE.png

Site Content > All Pages View
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfwK0.png

Comment: What you means? Add a screenshot,  pls

Comment: Please check post (edited) to see screenshot. So I added UTM codes to the site and I can obviously track them by going under All Campaigns. However, I notice that I can also see the UTM source and medium come through under my regular page views report as well. I was just wondering if that is normal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source / medium is a session level dimension, so in your second report you can see the pages visited from a session with that source / medium.

Anyway, if you are using UTMs in internal link you are making a big mistake because every time these change Google Analytics will start a new session.

These parameters must be used to monitor the sources entering the site, not the movements between the pages of the site.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Are you saying that by doing this, I could technically be duplicating session data on my own site, or at least Google Analytics would see it that way?

Comment: Yes, using the utm in that way you generates a new session every time the utm changes.